# Laravel Datatables 1 => active / 0 => not active

Tags: laravel, datatables

I'm using Laravel Framework and yajrabox datatables.

I have a table of users with 2 columns , a status column and a type of account column. Both of these holds ints.

How can I change these ints to strings? How can I perform an db request on the values of the $users variable in the cntroller?

Also is it possible to concat 2 columns into 1? So first_name and last_name into 1 column?

My current setup :

userlist.blade.php

```
@extends('app')
@section('content')
<div class='portlet light bordered '>
    <div class='portlet-title'>
        <div class='caption font-red-sunglo'>
            Ledenbeheer
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <a id='create' href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-circle red-sunglo">
                Nieuw lid </a>
            <a id='excel_import' href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-circle btn-default">
                <i class="fa fa-fax"></i>Excel import </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='portlet-body'>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="users-table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Naam</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Account type</th>
                <th>Created At</th>
                <th>Updated At</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>
@stop
@push('scripts')
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#users-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{!! route('configuratie_leden.data') !!}',

    });
});
 </script>
 @endpush
```

UserController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use yajra\Datatables\Facades\Datatables;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
//
public function getIndex(){

    $users =  User::all();

    return view('users.userlist');
}

public function anyData(){

    $users = User::select(['first_name','email','status','account_type','created_at','updated_at']);

    return Datatables::of($users)->make();
}
```

}

Routes :

```
// Routes module configuratie
Route::controller('configuratie_leden','UserController',
[
   'getIndex' => 'configuratie_leden',
    'anyData' => 'configuratie_leden.data'
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript solution:

```
columns: [
    { 
        data: 'status', 
        name: 'status',
        render: function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
           return data ? "active" : "not active" ;
        }
    }
]
```

That's how you can change int to string. When data is 1, it will print "active".

> Also is it possible to concat 2 columns into 1? So first_name and last_name into 1 column?

Yes it is. You do it in your query.

```
$users = User::select([
        DB::raw("CONCAT(users.name,'-',users.surname) as name_surname"),
        'email',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    ]);
```

Example: http://datatables.yajrabox.com/eloquent/post-column-search

Answer (score 0):

For column types, you can define attribute casts in your User model class

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'status' => 'string',
        'account_type' => 'string',
    ];

    protected $appends = ['full_name'];

    public function getFullNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
    }
}
```